# Rating for anonymous users plus redirection to the login page

Tags: ubercart, rating

I am using the Fivestar module for product rating with Ubercart. I want to enable rating for anonymous users. At the same time, when the user rates the product, this must be redirect to login page.

Is there any possibilities for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Voting Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/voting_rules) module.

> Administrators can configure actions to occur when a user submits a
>   vote, when a user deletes a vote, and when the results of a vote are
>   calculated. Currently, Voting Rules supports votes on nodes, users,
>   and comments.

I didn't test it, but using it is possible to achieve what you want with the the Rules module.

Comment: I have installed voting rules module. But I cannot able to find where to config that rule.